# Integration test pass on InteliJ runner but not on gradle

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, spring-cloud-stream

We are working on a project using `spring-cloud-stream`, with `rabbitmq` as message broker and `gradle`.

For testing purposes we are running a docker container with rabbitmq instance.

application.yaml:

```
spring
  rabbitmq:
    host: localhost
```

I have this test:

```
@DirtiesContext(classMode = BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT)
public class TasksProcessorIT {

  @Test
  public void shouldConsumeDeleteUserTask() {
    userRepository.insert(INITIAL_USER).block();
    final AtomicReference<Message<?>> msgRef = new AtomicReference<>();
    inboundEventsChannel.subscribe(msgRef::set);

    outboundTasksChannel.send(DELETE_USER_TASK);
    await().atMost(FIVE_SECONDS)
            .untilAtomic(msgRef, notNullValue());

    final Message<?> receivedEvent = msgRef.get();
    assertNotNull(receivedEvent);
    assertEquals(USER_DELETED, typeHeader(receivedEvent));
    assertNull(userRepository.findAll().blockFirst());
  }
}
```

It passes running on Intelij Runner, but fails when calling `gradle test`, I wonder why...

This is the logged cause:

`Caused by: org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers`

Comment: That doesn't appear to be a full test nor your are providing a full stack trace so it would be difficult to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: See my answer, please. Not 100%, but possible.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you have some data in the RabbitMQ queue in between different tests, but since you subscribe to the channel exactly in the test method, that might be already late, just because the Listener Container has already consumed message(s) from the queue.

Consider to clean up queues for testing in between tests.